# Set common legend for multiple categoric plots ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating five plots within a for loop that are stacked columns. There are 10 numbers that are factors on a scale from 0 to 9. Not every plot has each of these factors, but I'd like to have common colors. e.g. all 1's are blue, all 9s are green.

I.e. if I have this list of colors, how do I apply it to the plots.

```
colLegend <- list('0' = '#A9CCE3',  # light blue
                  '1' = '#A3E4D7',  # light green
                  '2' = '#27AE60',   # DARK GREEN
                  '3' = '#F7DC6F',    # YELLOW
                  '4' = '#F8C471',   # ORANGE
                  '5' = '#D35400',    # RED
                  '6' = '#117864',  # DARK TEAL
                  '7' = '#AF7AC5',   # PURPLE
                  '8' = '#2E4053',    # NAVY
                  '9' = '#616A6B')    # GREY
```

#### Current code

```
## plot stacked percentage of each value

labels <- c('19', '20', '22')

# create tally of each Ellenberg value

j = 1
for (df in ellenCatTab){
  dfName <- names(ellenCatTab)[j]
  j = j + 1
  
  df = df[,5:31]
  tidy <- df %>%
    gather(key='Quadrat', value='Ellenberg')
  tidy <- na.omit(tidy)
  tally <- tidy %>%
    count(Quadrat, Ellenberg)
  tally$Ellenberg <- as.factor(tally$Ellenberg)
  tally <- as.data.table(tally)
  tally[, c('Q', 'Year') := tstrsplit(tally$Quadrat, "_", fixed=TRUE)][]
  tally$Q <- sub('X', 'Q', tally$Q)
  
  stacked <- ggplot(tally, aes(fill=Ellenberg, y=n, x=Quadrat)) +
    geom_bar(position='stack', stat='identity') +
    ggtitle(dfName) +
    labs(x='Year', y='Number of Plants') +
    scale_x_discrete(labels=labels) +
    theme_classic() +
    facet_wrap(~ Q, nrow=1, scales='free_x')
  plot(stacked)
  
  ggsave(plot=stacked,
         file=paste0(dfName, '_stacked.png'),
         limitsize=FALSE,
         width=250, height=200, units='mm')

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding this worked:

```
scale_fill_manual(values = colLegend)
```